# Error : OSError: [WinError 126] Le module spécifié est introuvable

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, ddl, torchvision

I am trying to install pytorch on Windows 10 in a virtual env and I am getting this error :

```
(test) C:\Users\Emmanuelle>py
Python 3.7.7 (default, May  6 2020, 11:45:54) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32

Warning:
This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has
not been activated.  Libraries may fail to load.  To activate this environment
please see https://conda.io/activation

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import torch
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Emmanuelle\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\__init__.py", line 81, in <module>
    ctypes.CDLL(dll)
  File "C:\Users\Emmanuelle\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] Le module spécifié est introuvable
```

How can I handle it ?

Answer (score 0):

you have issue with your environment.
asper the errortraceback shows your conda environment isn't activated activate the environment using conda activate  .

If you are using pipenv or virtualenv then make sure you download pytorch using pip

Comment: @ I activate it using conda but the problem still remains

Comment: are you using " conda install -c pytorch pytorch"